# How to group result in the same line : Many to Many relationship by using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables join by Many-to-Many relationship, I create the 3rd table, and I have a query like this one :

```
SELECT  product.product_name, provider.provider_name 
FROM  product, provider, provider_product 
WHERE product.id_product = provider_product.ref_product 
AND provider.id_provider = provider_product.ref_provider
```

I need to group my result by product_name and the result must be in the same line, like that : if a product have a lot of providers : 
my result will be :

```
product.product_name | provider.provider_name
this is my first product 1   | this is provider1 / this is provider2 / this is provider3
```

As you see, Providers are in the same line, and they are splitting by `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

```
SELECT  product.product_name, GROUP_CONCAT(provider.provider_name SEPARATOR '/') 
FROM  product, provider, provider_product 
WHERE product.id_product = provider_product.ref_product 
AND provider.id_provider = provider_product.ref_provider 
GROUP BY product.product_name
```